# How does the pandas library implements its strange Python syntax?

Tags: python, pandas, syntax

I'm using Python for some projects, but I still have no idea how a library like `pandas` can redefine the core syntax of the Python language.

This code generates no error, but whatever I try to implement (outside of pandas library) nothing will be accepted and executed by the runtime, unlike this pandas code:

```
df[['col_x', 'col_y']]
# or
df.loc['col_x']
```

I could try to implement similar syntax, e.g.: I can use a function to pass or return a data structure similarly like this:

```
df([['col_x', 'col_y']])
# or
df = [['col_x', 'col_y']]
# or
df.loc()['col_x']
# or
df.loc = ['col_x']
```

but it's not close to the syntax of the pandas library.
But if I leave out the parentheses `()` it will generate a syntax error.

- How does the pandas library implement this custom syntax?
- Could I define any custom syntax for a new library, e.g. `df[[+]]`?
- Can someone explain this with simple Python concepts?

Comment: Pandas doesn't add any new syntax to Python. Everything you show above is valid Python syntax.

Comment: `foo[bar]` is just indexing, it effectively calls [`foo.__getitem__(bar)`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__). It's not custom syntax (which you couldn't do without also maintaining your own Python interpreter).

Comment: In short: Python allows you to define an interface for your custom objects that take advantage of Python's syntax. For example, if you have a class named `MyThing`, implementing the method `MyThing.__getitem__(item)` means that your class instances now support the syntax `my_thing[item]`.

Comment: if doesn't add any new syntax, then how can pandas return a `pandas.Series` on `df['x']` but returns `pandas.DataFrame` on `df[['x']]`?

Comment: Why would that require new syntax? That's up to `DataFrame.__getitem__`, it could do e.g. `if isinstance(key, list): <return dataframe>`.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: `df[[+]]` wouldn't work anywhere, because `[+]` isn't valid, because `+` isn't an expression.

Answer (score 1):

The following is an example class which implements `__getitem__` and a `loc` property:

```py
class Test:
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        if isinstance(index, list):
            return 'DataFrame'
        else:
            return 'Series'

    @property
    def loc(self):
        return self
    

test = Test()
print(test['foo'])  # Series
print(test[['foo']])  # DataFrame
print(test.loc['foo'])  # Series
```

Answer (score 1):

the `[]` syntax calls the `__getitem__` method of python so you could reproduce this behaviour like this:

```
class FakeLocObject:
    
    def __init__(self, caller_id):
        self.id = caller_id
    
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return f"hello {key} of {self.id}"

    
class FakeDFObject:
    
    def __init__(self, my_id):
        self.id = my_id
        
    @property
    def loc(self):
        return FakeLocObject(self.id)
```

them

```
foo = FakeDFObject(42)
foo.loc["world"]
```

gives `'hello world of 42'`

you can look into more details in the [python data model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html) but the general idea is that a lot of the python syntax (`.`, `()`, `[]`, `==` ...) is actually syntax sugar that will call methods that start with `__` which gives you the ability to make custom object where the "logical" usage is a non-trivial implementation